# polymorphism syntax using base

Tags: polymorphism

In my Microsoft tutorial it is said that if you want to invoke a method from a derived class you this to place 'base.' in front of the method you want to call.

`base.MethodOnBaseClass();`

But when I test this it works also without 'base.'
Just:

`MethodOnBaseClass();`

Can somebody explain why the second option is also working while my Microsoft tutorial says I have to use 'base.'.

Comment: ... which langage?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please specify which programming language you use? I assume you are programming a C# Application.

Also, please give some code snippets and tell us what you are trying to achieve.

From what i can tell you are trying to access a baseclass function from a childclass. This can be done, using the base keyword (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base).

Your described behaviour could have multiple causes, but the easiest is that you derived a function from a class and didn't override it afterwards. Then the basefunction and the childfunction would be the same. To clarify please post more information.

Comment: Yes I am using C#

Comment: As I said there are several reasons base.Method() and Method() give the same result. One easy to understand would be the following: 
Imagine a class animal with the function live and makeSound. live should have the same output in all children and the baseclass like: "I live", make sound should defer from every animal. So you let dog inherit from animal and override the makeSound function (early binding). You can now let the dog make to different sounds by calling the different makesSound functions but no matter how you call the live function it will always say "I live".